# paging in facebook graph api return error code : 368

Tags: node.js, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get comment out of a post by doing a loop when requesting to graph api url and this is their response :

```
 "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "< string>",
            "after": "< string>"
        },
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<string>"
    },
```

so I follow the link in next and this happen :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "It looks like you were misusing this feature by going too fast. You\u2019ve been temporarily blocked from using it.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 368,
      "error_data": {
         "sentry_block_data": "",
         "help_center_id": 0,
         "is_silent": false
      },
      "error_subcode": 3252001,
      "error_user_msg": "",
      "fbtrace_id": ""
   }
}
```

seem like facebook block me out temporaily, I need a long term solutions, anyway to get through facebook rate limit ? even thought I tried delay my request but seem like the main problem was number of comment I get / time.

The problem seems to be solved in the short term but in the long term has anyone find out a better way to avoid the rate limit?

Comment: currently I need more information about their rate limit is it depend on requested obj or more likely on per request, ty.